# Github Actions: Unable to open DISPLAY during tests with JavaFX 13

Tags: github-actions

I use Github Actions to automatically build and test my project with maven, but it fails during the tests. 
Here is the error message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY

Since my tests are using UI, it sounds like I need to enable the graphical interface, but I don't know how I can do that. I am using JavaFX13. You can see the complete build log on the [github page](https://github.com/N3ROO/javafx-nero-engine/commit/c3fee221b3b1534f2e94503e7d38c9842aa94f5f/checks?check_suite_id=297881369).

Here is the script that I use:

```
name: Maven build

on: 
  pull_request:
    branches: master
  push:
    branches: master


jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 13
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 13
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

I got it working on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/N3ROO/javafx-nero-engine/builds/608042239) by using:

```
services:
  - xvfb
```

and

```
before_script:
  - "export DISPLAY=:99.0"
```

But I could not find anything to make it working with Github actions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

Adding xvfb-run before the command worked for me:

```
xvfb-run mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```